# Filter results from nested Arrays (small React application)

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to solve a challenge found on FrontEndMentor. In this excercise i have to map through a Data.Js file and show the content. After i'll have to filter those results according to various categories clicking on the respective buttons. Here is my App.js component:

```
function App() {

  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState(Data)

  const filterThis = (e, type)=>{

   let categorySelected =  e.target.value; 
   console.log(categorySelected);

   if(type==="role"){
     setJobs(Data.filter(job=> job.role===categorySelected))
   } else if (type==="level"){
    setJobs(Data.filter(job=> job.level===categorySelected))
   }else if(type==="languages"){
      ???????
   }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header></header>
      <div className="container">
       {jobs.map(card=>{
         return (
           <Card 
            id={card.id} 
            company={card.company} 
            logo={card.logo} 
            isNew={card.new} 
            isFeatured={card.featured}
            position={card.position}
            role={card.role}
            level={card.level}
            postedAt={card.postedAt}
            contract={card.contract}
            location ={card.location}
            languages={card.languages}
            tools={card.tools}
            filterThis={filterThis}
            jobs={jobs}

            />
         )
       })} 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the Card.js component :

```
const Card =({id, company, logo, isNew, isFeatured,  position, role, level, postedAt, contract, location, languages,tools, filterThis})=>{
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <img src={logo}/>
            <div className="main">
            <div className="highlights">
             <p className="company">{company}</p>

             <p className="new">{isNew?"NEW!":null}</p>
             <p className="featured">{isFeatured?"FEATURED":null}</p>    
            </div>

            <h3>{position}</h3>
             <div className="description">
             <p>{postedAt}</p>
             <p>{contract}</p>
             <p>{location}</p> 
             </div>

             </div>
             <div className="buttons">
                 <Button filterThis ={filterThis}  tools={tools}  languages={languages} role={role} level={level}/>
             </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Card;
```

The Button.js component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Button = ({role, jobs, level, languages, tools, filterThis}) =>{

    return (
        <div>
            <button value={role} onClick={(e)=>filterThis(e,"role")}>{role}</button>
            <button value={level} onClick={(e)=>filterThis(e,"level")}>{level}</button>

            {languages && languages.map(lang=>{
                return (
                <button value={lang} onClick={(e)=>filterThis(e,"languages", lang)}>{lang}</button>
                )
            })}
             {tools && tools.map(tool=>{
                return (
                <button value={tool} onClick={(e)=>filterThis(e,"tools")}>{tool}</button>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

And the Data.js where i pull the data from:

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Photosnap",
    "logo": "/images/photosnap.svg",
    "new": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Senior",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "company": "Manage",
    "logo": "./images/manage.svg",
    "new": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Fullstack Developer",
    "role": "Fullstack",
    "level": "Midweight",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Part Time",
    "location": "Remote",
    "languages": ["Python"],
    "tools": ["React"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "company": "Account",
    "logo": "./images/account.svg",
    "new": true,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Junior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Junior",
    "postedAt": "2d ago",
    "contract": "Part Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["React", "Sass"]
  },
```

Now i can correctly display on the front end the data and i can successfully filter the Role and the Level. The problem is trying to map those nested arrays "languages" and "tools". I can't find a way to map and filter them (while inside the Button component i mapped them without problems, but now filtering is the problem).

Hope i was clear, thank you for the help guys!

Comment: Could you make a codesandbox with this code so I can help you better?

Comment: Could you attached some screenshots whats problem you face?

Comment: if you are receiving the return result of the filter it returns an array as well so you'll most likely have to map the filter return or do something like lang[0] or tool[0].

Comment: I will try guys to put in a code Sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hooks-ov20f?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this. 
But anyway, you will need to add a clear button that will refresh your default object.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";
// import { filter } from "async";
import Data from "./data.js";
import Card from "./Card";

function App() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState(Data);

  const filterThis = (e, type) => {
    let categorySelected = e.target.value;
    const filteredData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));

    if (type === "languages" || type === "tools") {
      let x = filteredData.filter(item => {
        if (typeof item[type] !== "undefined") {
          if (item[type].includes(e.target.value)) {
            return item;
          }
        }
      });
      setJobs(x);
    } else {
      setJobs(filteredData.filter(job => job[type] === categorySelected));
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain in few words what this code is doing and if this is the best practice when mapping through nested arrays?

Comment: @ChirstianaEriksten Well, the whole idea was to clone your default Data object before starting to filter it, the rest are just native javascript functions.  const filteredData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));  Once you have the filtered object, just set the state with it and you're done.setJobs([])  
As long as you will use natively javascript functions and keep the code clean and easy to read, it is a good practice. Idk if it is really the best, but this is how I would to the filtering over that array of objects.Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Awesome, it does perfectly make sense. Thank you!